# Input tag type number for credit card

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 input tags.

```
<input type="number" class="br1" name="first">
<input type="number" class="br1" name="secound">
<input type="number" class="br1" name="third">
<input type="number" class="br1" name="fourth">
```

I want to set maxlength (4 numbers) for every input tag. I tried to set maxlength but it doesn't work. Also, when I enter 4 numbers in one input tag, I want to automaticlly input in next input tag.

Thanks.

Comment: define *"doesn't work"* and specify which browser(s) along with providing actual sample of setting `maxlength` as per [mcve]

Comment: google chrome, when i set maxlength="4", i can insert more than 4 numbers

Comment: spelling is wrong in last comment

Comment: I corrected, length

Comment: You should also take a look at the "luhn algorithm" for validating card numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `maxlength` change type of input to text. Then you can parse all you your inputs strings to a number.

```js
$(".br1").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      var $next = $(this).next('.br1');
      if ($next.length)
          $(this).next('.br1').focus();
      else
          $(this).blur();
    }
});

$(".btn").click(function() {
 var string = "";
 $(".br1").each(function() {
  string += this.value;
 });
 number = parseInt(string);
 console.log(number);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="br1" name="first" maxlength=4>
    <input type="text" class="br1" name="secound" maxlength=4>
    <input type="text" class="br1" name="third" maxlength=4>
    <input type="text" class="br1" name="fourth" maxlength=4>
    <button class="btn">toNumber</button>
```

Comment: @Lazar On StackOverflow it is better to select the provided answer as a solution than thanking in a comment. It will in turn convey your gratitude to the answer provider and what is most important it will help future users with similar problem. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Use max="9999" and min="0000" to set the maximum value for input type number.

As per http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#the-maxlength-and-minlength-attributes maxlength is not valid for input of type number.

[image]

Comment: but i want only 4

Comment: @Lazar I modified the answer.

Comment: maxlength is not valid for input of type number?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input` event attached to `.br1` elements, `.slice()` with parameters `0`, `-1` to remove character if `.length` of `.value` is greater than `4`

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".br1");
for (let input of inputs) {
  input.oninput = () => {
    if (input.value.length > 4) {
      input.value = input.value.slice(0, -1)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="br1" name="first">
<input type="number" class="br1" name="secound">
<input type="number" class="br1" name="third">
<input type="number" class="br1" name="fourth">
```

Answer (score 0):

It as simple as posible, Try this:

```js
$("input[type=number]").keypress(function (e) {
    var el = $(this);
    var currentValue = el.val();
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which);
    if (currentValue.length === 3) {
        el.val(currentValue + char);
        e.preventDefault();
        el.next().focus();
    } else if (currentValue.length >= 4) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

```css
input[type=number]{
width:60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <input type="number" class="br1" name="first">
    <input type="number" class="br2" name="first">
    <input  type="number" class="br3" name="first">
    <input type="number" class="br4" name="first">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using only javascript. Also note the `maxLength` attribute don't work on number, so you may need to use input type='text'

Here is snippet

```
 // get the input
    var inputBox = document.getElementsByClassName("br1")
    // loop through the array of input
    for (var i = 0; i < inputBox.length; i++) {
      // creating a closure
      (function(x) {
        // adding event listener to each of the input
        inputBox[x].addEventListener('keydown', function(x) {
          // checking value of maxLength
          var maxLength = parseInt(this.attributes["maxlength"].value, 10);
          // length of the input value
          var myLength = this.value.length;
          // if both are equal then find the next sibling
          if (myLength >= maxLength) {
            var next = this.nextElementSibling
            // if the next sibling is input, set focus to it
            if (next.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input") {
              next.focus();
            }
          }
        })
      }(i))
    }
```